# Genesys Workspace Desk. Edit. get information

Tags: c#, genesys

I am pretty new in programming and I have developed few small apps.

Now I want to create simple Window based App "communicating" with Genesys

What does app do is when you get call through Genesys there is textbox where time is counted.

Now my "stopwatch" app should start counting in same time. SHOULD

There is issue, I am not sure how to connect or get info from Genesys interface without API

I know for most of you is dumb question but for me, beginner not so :)

I would be really glad if someone from you can help me here or give me advice.

My app of course have more functions and they are working without issue, that is the last thing what I need.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far

Comment: Please be a bit more specific when asking a question: *What have you tried so far with a code example?* ([I downvoted because there is no code](//idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/)) / *What do you expect?* / *What error do you get?* **For Help take a look at "[How to ask](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"**

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are referring to Genesys 'proper', not cloud or any new variants, you need to license the Genesys SDK, the protocol is proprietary. There is a Rest API available via Workspace Web Edition but that also requires license to use. Licenses are per agent!

Comment: Seems OP asked for method without API, so I am guessing the answer is that is not possible.

Comment: I'm not sure what "without API" really means and thought the OP was saying he had no API not that he needed a solution without an API. There are three ways - Genesys SDK, Genesys Web Services and Workspace Desktop Edition customisation.